# Possible Bug with Swift 3 mixing Protocols, Extensions, and Class Inheritence

Tags: swift, inheritance, protocols, swift3, protocol-extension

I am learning all about swift, OOP, and POP.  I have been mixing them together to make an abstract base class when I came across some unexpected behavior.  It is best expressed in code, I will show it working as expected, and then as unexpected (to me at least).  The code is long, but simple.  Here it is working properly:

```
protocol GodsWill           {          func conforms() }
extension GodsWill          {          func conforms() { print("Everything conforms to God's Will") } }
class TheUniverse: GodsWill {          func conforms() { print("The Universe conforms to God's Will") } }
class Life: TheUniverse     { override func conforms() { print("Life conforms to God's Will") } }
class Humans: Life          { override func conforms() { print("Though created by God, Humans think they know better") } }

let universe = TheUniverse()
let life = Life()
let humans = Humans()

universe.conforms()
life.conforms()
humans.conforms()
print("-------------------------")
let array:[GodsWill] = [universe,life,humans]
for item in array { item.conforms() }
```

And here is the output:

```
The Universe conforms to God's Will
Life conforms to God's Will
Though created by God, Humans sometimes think they know better
-------------------------
The Universe conforms to God's Will
Life conforms to God's Will
Though created by God, Humans sometimes think they know better
```

This is exactly as I would suspect.  But I ran into this problem in my app when the first class didn't have a custom implementation of conforms(), like this:

```
protocol GodsWill           {          func conforms() }
extension GodsWill          {          func conforms() { print("Everything conforms to God's Will") } }
class TheUniverse: GodsWill {  }
class Life: TheUniverse     {          func conforms() { print("Life conforms to God's Will") } }
class Humans: Life          { override func conforms() { print("Though created by God, Humans sometimes think they know better") } }

let universe = TheUniverse()
let life = Life()
let humans = Humans()

universe.conforms()
life.conforms()
humans.conforms()
print("-------------------------")
let array:[GodsWill] = [universe,life,humans]
for item in array { item.conforms() }
```

Notice here that TheUniverse does not have a custom implementation of conforms().  Here is the output:

```
Everything conforms to God's Will
Life conforms to God's Will
Though created by God, Humans sometimes think they know better
-------------------------
Everything conforms to God's Will
Everything conforms to God's Will
Everything conforms to God's Will
```

The first three print() lines are exactly what I expect and want, but the last three really baffle me.  Since conforms() is a protocol requirement, they should be identical to the top three lines.  But I am getting behavior as if conforms() was implemented in the protocol extension, but not listed as a protocol requirement.  There is nothing about this in The Swift Programming Language reference manual.  And [this WWDC video](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2015/408/?time=1754) at exactly 30:40 in proves my point.

So, have I done something wrong, misunderstood the functionality, or have I found a bug in swift 3?

Answer (score 1):

Upon further investigation, I don't think this is quite related to the WWDC video.

The Universe doesn't define the `conforms` method, so calling `conforms` on the universe will print "Everything...".

Life defines a `conforms` method. However, since it inherits from the universe, which already has an implementation of `conforms` because of the extension, the `conforms` method isn't really required by the protocol. Therefore, the protocol kind of ignores the `conforms` method in the `Life` class. In other words, the `conforms` method in `Life` is *shadowing* the `conforms` method in protocol extension, as we can see in the output of:

```
let a: TheUniverse = Life()
a.conforms()
Life().conforms()
// output:
// Everything conforms to God's Will
// Life conforms to God's Will
```

Humans have another `conforms` method. This time, it is defined with `override`. However, this `override` does not override the `conforms` method in the protocol extension. Instead, it overrides the `conforms` method in `Life`, which is a direct superclass of `Humans`. This can be proved by the output of the below code:

```
let a: Life = Humans()
a.conforms()
// output:
// Though created by God, Humans sometimes think they know better
```

So after all, the method in the protocol extension is not overridden. So when you create some objects and put it into [GodsWill], the shadowing has no effect, thus the protocol extension method is called.

Comment: So what would be the solution for this problem?  I have multiple classes which will conform to GodsWill, all of which I want to have the same default implementation.  I guess if I could include a stub in the base class that simply calls the extension implementation, it would complete the circuit and function properly.  I tried this: `func conforms() { super.conforms() }` in TheUniverse but this is a compile time error.  I tried `func conforms() { (self as GodsWill).conforms() }` in TheUniverse, but this is an infinite loop.  How would I call conforms() on GodsWill from TheUniverse?

Comment: @mogelbuster Oh yes I forgot to mention that! Just don't make anything inherit from `TheUniverse`. Why can't `Life` directly conform to `GodsWill`?

Comment: `Life` needs to inherit from `TheUniverse`, and `Life` needs to conform to `GodsWill`.  That would work, except `TheUniverse` also needs to conform to `GodsWill`.  So `Life` can't directly conform to `GodsWill`.  I could simply put the default implementation of `conforms()` inside `TheUniverse`, but lets say reality is larger than we thought, and I have two more base classes `EvilParallelUniverse` and `HeavenlyParallelUniverse` both of which must conform to `GodsWill`.  They all use the default implementation of `conforms()` but their myriad subclasses must customize that implementation.

Comment: I suppose I could make `GodsWill` a base class to the universe classes, instead of a protocol, but this would cut back on code reuse and extensibility of `GodsWill`, which is exactly the purpose of swift protocol extensions.  Alternatively, I could make a new base class `TheMultiverse` which is the superclass to all the universes, delete the protocol extension of `GodsWill` (but keep the protocol itself) and move the default implementation of `conforms()` inside `TheMultiverse`.  But if I have to do all that, then what is the purpose of protocol extensions?  It seems like a swift design flaw.